# What does the .ino file extension mean

Tags: ino

**What does the `.ino` file extension mean?**

We have `.cpp` meaning C++, `.py` meaning Python, `.exe` meaning executable and so-on.They're obvious. The `.pde` file type that sketches previously used, I think, comes from *processing development environment* (the arduino IDE being based* on / inspired by [processing](https://processing.org)).  But what does `.ino` mean?

There's plenty that explains what such files are, but nothing explains what those three letters mean, if anything.

<sub>* source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)</sub>

Comment: The last 3 letters of *Arduino*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ardu***ino***

That's all there is to say about that really.

---

As [commented in the source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.0/build/shared/revisions.txt#L5-L7)

> The file extension for sketches has changed from .pde to .ino, to avoid
> conflicts with the Processing software ("ino" are the last three letters
> in "Arduino").

Comment: A [citation](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.0/build/shared/revisions.txt#L5-L7), if anyone cares to have one.

Comment: @timemage Very good! Thanks for the citation.

Comment: Nice one @timemage I've added that to the answer.

Comment: And .ard was probably already taken https://fileinfo.com/amp/extension/ard

Answer (score 3):

"Arduino" is an Italian word, and "ino" is the suffix which lends itself well to a filename extension.

From [Google Translate of Italian ino](https://translate.google.com/?sl=it&tl=en&text=ino%0A%0A1%0ASuffisso%20alterativo%20di%20aggettivi%20e%20sostantivi%3B%20nei%20primi%20ha%20valore%20diminutivo-vezzeggiativo%2C%20talvolta%20con%20sfumatura%20ironica%20(%20biondino%2C%20carino%20)%2C%20oppure%20significa%20appartenenza%20etnica%20(%20alessandrino%2C%20cadorino%20)%2C%20collegamento%20con%20materie%20(%20argentino%2C%20salino%20)%3B%20nei%20secondi%2C%20oltre%20ad%20avere%20valore%20diminutivo-vezzeggiativo%20(%20gattino%2C%20pensierino%20)%2C%20indica%20pure%20un%20mestiere%20(%20ciabattino%2C%20tamburino%20)%2C%20uno%20strumento%20o%20arnese%20o%20apparecchio%20(%20cerino%2C%20lavandino%20)%3B%20in%20alcuni%20casi%20%C3%A8%20applicato%20a%20verbi%20(%20imbianchino%2C%20accendino%20).%0A2%0AIn%20chimica%20organica%2C%20suffisso%20che%20nella%20nomenclatura%20ufficiale%20indica%20gli%20idrocarburi%20acetilenici%2C%20cio%C3%A8%20gli%20alchini%20(%20etino%20).&op=translate):

> ino
>
> 1. Suffisso alterativo di aggettivi e sostantivi; nei primi ha valore diminutivo-vezzeggiativo, talvolta con sfumatura ironica ( biondino, carino ), oppure significa appartenenza etnica ( alessandrino, cadorino ), collegamento con materie ( argentino, salino ); nei secondi, oltre ad avere valore diminutivo-vezzeggiativo ( gattino, pensierino ), indica pure un mestiere ( ciabattino, tamburino ), uno strumento o arnese o apparecchio ( cerino, lavandino ); in alcuni casi è applicato a verbi ( imbianchino, accendino ).
> 2. In chimica organica, suffisso che nella nomenclatura ufficiale indica gli idrocarburi acetilenici, cioè gli alchini ( etino ).

> 1. Alterative suffix of adjectives and nouns; in the former it has a diminutive-pet name, sometimes with an ironic tinge (blond, cute), or it means ethnic affiliation (Alexandrian, Cadore), connection with materials (Argentine, saline); in the latter, in addition to having a diminutive-pet name (kitten, little thought), it also indicates a trade (cobbler, drummer), an instrument or tool or apparatus (match, sink); in some cases it is applied to verbs (painter, lighter).
> 2. In organic chemistry, suffix that in the official nomenclature indicates acetylenic hydrocarbons, i.e. alkynes (ethin).